# Is there a way to make Jekyll render pull request diffs?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jekyll, pull-request

tl;dr: We're using the combination of GitHub and Jekyll with Textile-backed pages to render an internal documentation set. Works great, except for one thing: It's really hard to read the diffs in the proposed changes.

**Longer version:**

We have a GitHub repo which contains a Jekyll installation and the Textile code that contains our documentation content. This document set evolves frequently as we design new aspects of our product. Our workflow for adding new docs looks like this:

1. Developer forks or branches the repo and modifies the Textile code to reflect the desired new changes.
2. When done, he/she submits a pull request to the original repo.
3. A designated group reviews this pull request and either approves it (merges it) or sends it back with comments.

At step 3, we typically find ourselves reading the "changed files" tab in the GitHub pull request page. This is suboptimal because the Textile code often runs beyond the screen width of the GitHub interface and the diff screen typically only contains a couple of lines of context. This is often not enough to really understand the proposed change.

**What I'd like to see happen:**

When the pull request is submitted or updated, a Jenkins (or similar) job runs and renders the content of the PR's branch *with* additions and deletions marked. (Imagine a <span class="addition"> or <span class="deletion"> surrounding the modifications.)

Anyone know if this has been done already? Or have any clever tips for implementing such if we're on our own?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I'm interested to see this too

Comment: Aw man, I totally forgot about this question. No, never found a good answer, but we're also not using Jekyll or Textile in this fashion any more.

Comment: Current answer seems to be that GitHub does a very nice job of rendering Markdown or AsciiDoc including diffs. That turns out to work very well for our current internal doc needs.